# System crashes after hibernation

Tags: linux-kernel, suspend, kernel-panic

OS: Bedrock Linux (basically Gentoo w/ AUR packages, I have had the same problem before hijacking the install)

Kernel: Tried 5.3.{0,1,2}-gentoo

Swap/FS info: LUKS volume on Btrfs, using swap file. On an SSD.

What I did:

- Echo resume device and offset to `/sys/power/resume` and `/sys/power/resume_offset` respectively.
- Suspend to disk with:

```
# echo disk > /sys/power/resume
```

- Turn on PC
- Initramfs echoes device major:minor to `/sys/power/resume`

What happens next:

- The display goes blank and comes back again at the resumed system. (normal behaviour I believe)
- Kernel outputs RIP multiple times that ends with end trace
- Some processes die
- Launching some programs gives a segmentation fault
- I can launch some programs like top, but there is a process stuck at 100% CPU
- The kernel eventually panics
- If it hasn't panicked yet, and I try to do REISUB to cleanly restart the system, killing processes (E & I) causes a kernel panic

The behaviour seems to range in severity randomly, sometimes the kernel panics almost immediately after resuming and other times it doesn't seem to panic although the system is still broken.

I have had no signs of file system corruption, it might be something to do with memory. I do believe that the memory is fine (I can use the system just fine, it's just that resuming from hibernation doesn't work well). I have used Arch on the system before and didn't have this problem, but not with the same kernels.

Does anyone know what is going on here, and how I could resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I disclaim any experience with Linux's support for suspend-to-disk and disk encryption, but...

> Swap/FS info: **LUKS** volume on ***Btrfs***, using **swap file**. On an SSD.

For **Btrfs** and **swap file**:

- Did you use a correct offset value? Because ["physical offset" reported on Btrfs might not actually be a real on-disk offset](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=202803).
- I did not see any step that your initramfs would put a proper swap file start offset into `/sys/power/resume_offset` when commencing *resume*. Does it do that?

For **LUKS** (disk encryption, I suppose?):

- Did you use a correct major:minor of the [*decrypted* virtual device](https://wiki.debian.org/Hibernation/Hibernate_Without_Swap_Partition#Tricks_when_the_system_is_fully_encrypted) to resume from?

Comment: 1. Yes, I used btrfs_map_physical when I used the correct offsets (and divided by 4096) 2. Yes, my initramfs script I made has this: echo ${RESUME_OFFSET} > /sys/power/resume_offset
echo ${RESUME_MAJMIN} > /sys/power/resume 3. I got the major:minor from lsblk, used the /dev/mapper/myvol one